# Como mover items entre 2 TreeView dinamicamente?

Tags: delphi, treeview, c++-builder

Tenho um TreeView que recebe como itens os campos de uma base de dados. Queria vincular esses campos à outro TreeView que já possui uma estrutura pré-definida. Seria algo como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente esse vínculo é feito utilizando o para arrastar os itens da esquerda para a direita.

Answer (score 0):

Como os itens da minha TreeView da direita sao fixos, resolvi o problema adicionando uma de cada vez, juntamente com seu filho. Segue o código:

// Adicionando items ao TreeView

```
TTreeNode *noPai;

noPai = trvDestino->Items->Add(NULL,"Matrícula");
trvDestino->Items->AddChild(noPai,trvOrigem->Items->Item[0]->Text);

noPai = trvDestino->Items->Add(NULL,"Unidade");
trvDestino->Items->AddChild(noPai,trvOrigem->Items->Item[1]->Text);

noPai = trvDestino->Items->Add(NULL,"Gabarito");
trvDestino->Items->AddChild(noPai,trvOrigem->Items->Item[2]->Text);

noPai = trvDestino->Items->Add(NULL,"Respostas");
for(int i=3;i< trvOrigem->Items->Count; i++){
  trvDestino->Items->AddChild(noPai,trvOrigem->Items->Item[i]->Text);
}
```